# Is there a way to pass data from one servlet to another whilst also passing the same data to a jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

In my scenario I have a servlet that passes an object to a JSP in the usual requestDispatcher way, however I also need this object for use in another servlet. Is there a method of passing this object to both the JSP to be displayed, and to the other servlet to be accessed?

Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer worked?

Comment: Sorry was busy, thanks for the help, worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, you can do something like this:

```
request.setAttribute("parameter",obj);
request.getRequestDispatcher("page/to/display/user").forward(req,res);
session.setAttribute("parameter",obj);
response.sendRedirect("servlet/to/redirect");
```

Comment: Where does "session" come from?

Comment: @eocsap `request.getSession()`